# Check an instance is in Spring 14 preview or not

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

In  has listed the sandboxes which are in Spring 14.  My sandbox is one of those, but any other way to ensure my instance is in Spring 14 preview release?

Comment: check the API version, by generating the enterprise WSDL or create/edit apex class.

Comment: As per document this should be spring 14 but the API version is still 29 and "Discover Winter 14"  is wriiten top right side

Comment: Are you sure the upgrade process has even started ? I thought that was gonna be next week.

Comment: According to Salesforce the upgrade will begin on Jan 10 2014.

Answer (score 0):

If your sandbox wasn't listed as one that will be upgraded to Spring 14, you'd need to complete a sandbox refresh from production prior to January 4th 2014.

Full instructions for moving to Spring 14 preview or staying on Winter 14 can be found at the following blog post:

http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/11/spring-14-sandbox-preview-instructions.html

Comment: As per document this should be spring 14 but the API version is still 29 and "Discover Winter 14" is wriiten top right side

Comment: From the blog post: "The Sandbox Preview window for Spring ‘14 is scheduled to begin January 10, 2014." - you'll be on winter 14 regardless of instance until that date.